# Python Beginning Program Dictionary and List Issue

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

Write a program that reads the contents of a random text file.  The program should create a dictionary in which the keys are individual words found in the file and the values are the number of times each word appears.

How would I go about doing this?

```
    def main():
    c = 0
    dic = {}
    words = set()
    inFile = open('text2', 'r')
    for line in inFile:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.replace('.', '')
        line = line.replace(',', '')
        line = line.replace("'", '')        #strips the punctuation
        line = line.replace('"', '')
        line = line.replace(';', '')
        line = line.replace('?', '')
        line = line.replace(':', '')
        words = line.split()        
     for x in words:
        for y in words:
            if x == y:
                c += 1
            dic[x] = c
print(dic)
print(words)

inFile.close()
```

main()

Sorry for the vague question.  Never asked any questions here before.  This is what I have so far.  Also, this is the first ever programming I've done so I expect it to be pretty terrible.

Comment: Do some python tutorials on the relevant subjects, try something or look up how to do it and come back should you get stuck

Comment: 1. Ask on StackOverflow  2. Get downvoted to oblivion  3. Attempt it yourself ..

Comment: For what it's worth, OP, this is getting downvoted because it's a request for a code dump. Questions that sound like "Do my homework for me" don't go over will on SO. I gave you some pointed tips in the right direction in my answer. I wouldn't expect anything more complete than that.

Comment: @wim To be fair.. the OP has now provided code

Comment: @user3570803, in the future.... "I have a homework assignment and don't know were to begin" is an honest and fair approach to getting your question answered.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    # code goes here
```

That's how you open a file

```
for line in infile:
    # code goes here
```

That's how you read a file line-by-line

```
line.strip().split()
```

That's how you split a line into (white-space separated) words.

```
some_dictionary['abcd']
```

That's how you access the key `'abcd'` in `some_dictionary`.

Questions for you:

1. What does it mean if you can't access the key in a dictionary?
2. What error does that give you? Can you catch it with a try/except block?
3. How do you increment a value?
4. Is there some function that **GETS** a default value from a dict if the key doesn't exist?

For what it's worth, there's also a function that does almost exactly this, but since this is pretty obviously homework it won't fulfill your assignment requirements anyway. It's in the `collections` module. If you're interested, try and figure out what it is :)

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks! I never imagined my 5k rep point would be hit on a question that should (probably) be deleted anywho :)

Comment: yeah, SO is great at sending mixed signals.  On one hand, "How dare you ask us to do your homework!!!", on the other other..."Well, let me take a look....".  Just goes to show that underneath our gruff nature is our need to feel useful, and satisfying that need outweighs the reward of conforming to the editorial policy.  :-)

Comment: Thank you all for the help.  I got it now!

Comment: you don't need `.strip()` when you call `.split()` after.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian true, but forgetting to use `str.strip` on a line of text from a file is sure to cause some errors down the line. Just because `str.split` will split on all whitespace doesn't make it bad practice to include in advice to an obvious beginner :)

Comment: `.strip`() is strictly redundant redundant before `.split()`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian if and only if you call `str.split` without a parameter. In that one situation it is unnecessary to call `str.strip` beforehand. In nearly EVERY OTHER situation, it is better to strip your line of leading and trailing whitespace before working with it. This isn't really so much an argument as a difference in opinion -- obviously the code would be CLEANER without, but then I didn't really write any code for him did I?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian it is best practice to `str.strip` a line of text from a file. `str.split` makes that unnecessary, but not harmful (frankly if your bottleneck is the speed at which you're reading data from a file, you're at a good spot for speed anyway, like as not). I find it better to instruct a beginning programmer in best practice rather than throw reasons why "Well normally you'd do X but because of Y you can do Z."

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian If it bothers you, feel free to edit it to change. I prefer my version but wouldn't veto an edit.

Comment: It doesn't bother me. I left the first comment for your benefit (I doubt OP can manage to understand any of the answers).

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three different approaches to add a new word to the dictionary and count the number of occurences in this file.

```
def add_element_check1(my_dict, elements):
    for e in elements:
        if e not in my_dict:
            my_dict[e] = 1
        else:
            my_dict[e] += 1

def add_element_check2(my_dict, elements):
    for e in elements:
        if e not in my_dict:
            my_dict[e] = 0
        my_dict[e] += 1            

def add_element_except(my_dict, elements):
    for e in elements:
        try:
            my_dict[e] += 1
        except KeyError:
            my_dict[e] = 1




my_words = {}

with open('pathtomyfile.txt', r) as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        words = [word.strip().lower() word in line.strip().split()]
        add_element_check1(my_words, words)
        #or add_element_check2(my_words, words)
        #or add_element_except(my_words, words)
```

If you are wondering which is the fastest? The answer is: it depends. It depends on how often a given word might occur in the file. If a word does only occur (relatively) few times, the try-except would be the best choice in your case.

I have done some simple [benchmarks here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/benchmarks/timeit_tests.ipynb?create=1#dict_ops)

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect job for the built in Python Collections class.  From it, you can import Counter, which is a dictionary subclass made for just this.

How you want to process your data is up to you.  One way to do this would be something like this

```
from collections import Counter 

# Open your file and split by white spaces
with open("yourfile.txt","r") as infile:
    textData = infile.read()
    # Replace characters you don't want with empty strings
    textData = textData.replace(".","")
    textData = textData.replace(",","")
    textList = textData.split(" ")

# Put your data into the counter container datatype
dic = Counter(textList)

# Print out the results
for key,value in dic.items():
    print "Word: %s\n Count: %d\n" % (key,value)
```

Hope this helps!

Matt

Comment: This is exactly the approach I would take, but since OP is presumably doing homework, I'm sure this won't work. Also try using `str.translate` with `string.ascii_punctuation` mapped to `None` and `map(str.lower,textList)` (or `str.casefold` if you're 3.x) since, you know, `"Hello"`,`"hello"`,`"Hello!"`, and `"hello,"` should all be the same word.

Comment: You're absolutely right Adam, I didn't see the blurb at the bottom of your post commenting on the collections module.  I've never used the `translate` or `ascii_punctuation` methods before.  I'll have a look into those.

Comment: Thank you this would work but as the other guy said I can't use the counter module.

Comment: @user1786981 `string.ascii_punctuation` doesn't exist, I made a boo boo lol. `string.punctuation` is what I meant (I was conflating it with `string.ascii_uppercase` and `string.ascii_lowercase`. `string.punctuation` is a string constant that is: `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_\`{|}~`. `transdict = str.maketrans({ch:None for ch in string.punctuation}); "a,.'!><<z".translate(trandsict) == "az"`